# Is there any limitation for publish message in pubnub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pubnub

Is there any limitation for send no of publish message in per second(or in any time interval) at pubnub?

Answer (score 0):

PubNub can handle as many publishes as you can send to it. The bottlenecks will be on the network you are on.

But what is your use case?